# How to Partition a Single HDD With Hardware RAID 0

Tags: linux, raid, centos-7, raid-0, parted

I have one SSD and one 10TB HDD.

All the OS stuffs (e.g. `/`, `/root`, `/var`, `/usr`, etc) are on the SSD.

And for a very dumb reason, I have to attach the 10TB to a RAID card (LSI MegaRAID SAS 9260-8i).  And so it is configured with RAID 0.

Now, I wonder whether any special care needs to be taken if I want to partition it.  I am on CentOS 7.

I tried to use `parted` to create two partitions and then use `mkfs.xfs` to format both partitions.

Then, I tried to run some test with `fio`, and it was stuck at 100% for like 10 mins.  Then I killed `fio` and issued a reboot command, but the machine didn't reboot, and someone in the data center had to manually power cycle it.

When it came back, the RAID utility/driver complained:

> All of the disks from your previous configuration are gone. If this is
> an unexpected message, then please power off your system and check
> your cables to ensure all disks are present. Press any key to
> continue, or press  to load the configuration utility.

The tech guy there had to get into MegaRAID WebOS to reconfigure it.

So I suspect that I couldn't just use `parted` to partition a hardware RAID 0 HDD?

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot have RAID 0 if you only have a single disk.  The minimum is 2 disks and that means you cannot have any faulty HDDs.

Answer (score 0):

One drive on a RAID controller is called JBOD - not RAID0 - but that's unrelated to your problem.

Possible cause #1:-

You hosed the boot block, which caused your problem.

Can you mount a DVD or ISO over a KVM and use the normal linux installer?  That does the partitioning with working boot blocks etc all for you.

Possible cause #2:-

Your existing system did not boot, because your server attempted to boot the new disk that you just formatted, instead of it's correct boot disk.

This could be caused by:
a) a new bootable disk arriving that wasn't there before, with a higher boot priority: possible solution: disable the boot flag
b) your new disk causing the existing disk number scheme to be different (e.g. your previous bootable "sda" is now "sdb")

Way to fix most of the above: move this new disk to a different cable, or go into the bios and select the correct boot order.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Sorry that I didn't provide enough detail.   I just updated my post.  The OS is installed on another drive (SSD).  So the OS part is fine.  Just the 10TB HDD is giving me trouble.  Hence, the vendor tried to replace a new HDD (same model), and a new SATA cable; at the end, even adding a RAID card to bypass the AMD SATA controller as we are guessing it is the issue.  But anyway, now, I just wonder whether I can just partition the HDD on JBOD just like a HDD not on JBOD?  Or some special care is needed.